# Dagger Parent Component scoping

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger, dagger-hilt, daggermock

If I use Core-component as parent component of my AppComponent , and the scope for the AppComponent is singleton. Is all the dependency derive from corecomponent would be singletone ? I mean Only one instance will be created for parent provided dependencies or multiple ?

Answer (score 0):

@Singleton does not mean "a single instance" as we know it from the desing pattern.

Basically when we talk about singletons we think about a Single instance created through the lifecycle of the application.

When we say @Singleton in Dagger - it is just "a name of a scope". Basically it means - a single instance created through the lifecycle of that Component.

That is the reason some people do not use @Singleton, but cretate @PerApp annotation so it us more clear and obvious.

My point is - you are pointing out the parent has a @Singleton scope. It doesn't matter. It could be the @Whatever scope. What you need to care about is the following:

- If dependencies comming from a parent Component are not scoped(you only put @Provides, but no @SomeScope annotation) every time this dependency is used(provided) somewhere it will be a new instance.
- On the other hand - if the parent Component has some scoped dependencies like in your case @Singleton or like I said: @WhateverScope - while the Component is alive it will provide only one instance for the time you are able to create, destroy, recreate many child components.
- But if you recreate the parent, even if you scope it with @Singleton - you will have a 2nd instance of the scoped dependencies for the same application lifecycle.